# SaveDialog suggested filenames to match extension filter

Tags: delphi, filter, tsavedialog

When my program displays a SaveDialog to save a file I can use the Filter and Filter Index properties to restrict the files displayed to certain extensions. Also, when I set the DefaultExt property then, as the user types a filename, matching files in the folder are displayed as suggestions in a dropdown box and one can be selected with the mouse.
For example if the filter is set to "*.xml" then only filenames matching that extension appear in the the dialog list of files. But if the user type "Test", then you will get a dropdown list of suggestion files like:
    TestA.doc
    TestB.xml
    Test123.pdf
    TestX.xml
(if those files are present in the folder)

But I would like the suggestion list to only contain the files that match the filter, such as *.xml. Is that possible? The problem is that users can hit the wrong suggestion and save their file with the wrong extension.

Comment: No. You can read an exhaustive explanation of what you can do with that dialog [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlgbox/open-and-save-as-dialog-boxes).

Answer (score 2):

TSaveDialog internally uses the [IFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775966(v=vs.85).aspx) interface of Windows. That interface doesn't offer any way in which to change how to filter files in suggestion dropdown text box of File Name field.

You can :

- Implement own dialog from scratch
- Use component like DexExpress which is not free
- Check result of save dialog after execution of it and validate the user selection file and show proper message to user if the file is not valid